# How to cancel the effect of \translate when I want to draw a radial line from the untranslated origin to the current point?

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following MWE first.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}

% draw the tangential lines
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=red]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \translate(!!CP)
        \lineto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
    }       
}
\end{pspicture}

% draw the radial lines
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=blue]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \translate(!!CP)
        \moveto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        \psline[liftpen=2](0,0)(!!CP)% draw from the UNTRANSLATED origin to the current point
    }       
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

It produces two output as follows.

[image][image]

### Objective

The red curve  is made by concatenating unit tangent vectors

```
\pscustom[linecolor=red]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \translate(!!CP)
        \lineto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
    }       
}
```

and the blue curve is not what I want to get.

```
\pscustom[linecolor=blue]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \translate(!!CP)
        \moveto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        \psline[liftpen=2](0,0)(!!CP)% draw from the UNTRANSLATED origin to the current point
    }       
}
```

The blue diagram should represent  a set of radial lines emerging from the origin to the tip of the unit tangent vector.

### Question

How to draw a line from the untranslated origin to the current point? In other words, how to draw a line from the absolute origin to the current point?

### Note

Please just add code in the given place holder below.

```
\pscustom[linecolor=blue]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        % you can add code here
        \translate(!!CP)
        \moveto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        %\psline[liftpen=2](0,0)(!!CP)% draw from the UNTRANSLATED origin to the current point
        % or you can add code here
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\translate(!!CP)` you move the whole coordinate system around, so that `(0,0)` no longer refers to the same origin. You can write the whole part without using `\translate`, but with relative line and move operations (`\rlineto` and `\rmoveto`):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% draw the tangential lines
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=red]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \rlineto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
    }       
}
\end{pspicture}

% draw the radial lines
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=blue]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \rmoveto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        \psline[liftpen=2](0,0)(!!CP)
    }       
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image][image]

If it's only about ignoring the translations, then you can define the origin as a node. The nodes saves the current matrix, and restores the very same point regardless of the translations and scaling which have been done in the meanwhile:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
% draw the radial lines
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pnode(0,0){Origin}
\pscustom[linecolor=blue]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \translate(!!CP)
        \moveto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        \psline[liftpen=2](Origin)(!!CP)
    }       
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no need for a new translate, rotating does it anyway.